# Can we store PDF or JPG file in Hive DB using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Whether we can store PDF or JPG, files in Hive DB.
How much data can we store in Hive DB, without having any performance issue, for the app.

How much data can we store in Hive DB, without having any performance issue, for the app.

Answer (score 0):

-- yes we can store pdf , jpg and png file in a hive databse.

-- this is a example for pick and store file in a hive

```
 Future<void> _pickAndSaveFile() async {
    try {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png'],
      );

      if (result != null) {
        File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
        String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
        String destinationPath = await _getLocalPath(fileName);
        File newFile = await file.copy(destinationPath);

        Box<String> filesBox = Hive.box<String>('files');
        filesBox.add(newFile.path);

        setState(() {
          _filePath = newFile.path;
        });

        print('File saved at: $_filePath');
      } else {
        // User canceled the picker
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error picking or saving file: $e');
    }
  }
```